# Signals vs. polling for I/O (uses very simple example of I/O)

Tags: process, kernel, io, signal, interrupts

I understand how hardware interrupts work. I have a basic question about I/O, and will use keyboard and characters from key presses as the context for the question.

In a general sense, do processes tend to use polling (the process polling the kernel) or signals (the kernel notifying the process) to access characters from a buffer in the kernel where they have been stored temporarily?

I understand how polling can be done with a simple loop.

As an even more specific example, when I type this question, is the browser polling the kernel (and, the polling is active while I have clicked in the text field), or, is the kernel using a signal and triggering a signal handler in the process managing this browser window text input field?

Comment: "*In a general sense, do processes tend to use polling (the process polling the kernel) or signals ..*" -- Neither. Preferred method in a multitasking OS is for a process to use blocking syscalls (e.g. I/O request). This lets the kernel efficiently handle syscalls with internal events, rather than the process burdening the kernel & system with the (less efficient) schemes you mention.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the OS, but as far as I know, both Windows and all Unix-like systems primarily use polling (i.e. the kind of polling where the process sleeps waiting for a blocking system call to return – not the kind of polling where the process keeps checking repeatedly). Signal usage is rare.

- In the most basic case, if the process wants to read synchronously from a single file handle, it will call read() or ReadFile() and the system call will block until data is available. (It might create several threads, each waiting for read() on a different file handle, but that's uncommon.)
- With multiple sources, the process would call poll() or WaitForMultipleObjects(), which also blocks until some event and eventually returns one of the given file handles which the process could read() from.

  When dealing with a large amount of sources, epoll or kqueue are preferred – I am not sure of the Windows equivalent; it might be IOCP or Overlapped I/O. (See also: the new io_uring API on Linux and the almost identical IoRing on Windows.)

Most larger programs are structured around a central "event loop" which will poll() on all sources, handle some events, then poll() again, repeat. For example, when you're using a web browser on Linux, two programs are involved:

1. the display server (such as Xorg for X11 or GNOME Shell for Wayland) has an event loop that polls for user input via /dev/input/* devices (from kernel) as well as application X11 or Wayland events via sockets (draw commands from graphical apps);
2. the browser has an event loop that polls for user input via its X11 or Wayland socket (from the display server) as well as network traffic from open sockets (e.g. active HTTP downloads).

There exist a few old "asynchronous I/O" APIs do use signals (the one from 4.2BSD, I believe?); setting the FASYNC flag will cause SIGIO to be sent; but overall it seems to be very rare. (And if a process is doing nothing but waiting to receive a signal, then it might as well just wait for a blocking poll() to return instead, without any of the hassle of signal handlers – especially without worrying about reentrancy or overflowing the signal queue...)

In fact, on Linux and FreeBSD, event-loop frameworks often choose to **receive signals via polling** – the program masks all signals from their normal delivery, then uses signalfd() to create a file handle that can be polled, and when a signal occurs a `struct siginfo` can be read from the signalfd handle at the process' own leisure (the event loop is responsible for calling the signal handler). Similarly, timer events can be delivered through timerfd without relying on SIGALRM and such.

Comment: "*the kind of polling where the process sleeps waiting for a blocking system call to return*" -- That's not "polling" at all, but rather event-driven.  The event/signal is all handled by/within the kernel. So the OP's expectation of "*the kernel notifying the process*" is concealed by the API when it simply returns from the blocking syscall. The actual results (e.g. latency and CPU efficiency) are essentially the same to the OP's definition of "*signal*" rather than the OP's definition of "*poll*".

Comment: thank you both. I agree with @sawdust that the blocking syscall is similar to my assumption of what "signal" would do. I don't have the terminology for this yet, but both of you have helped me with some terms now so I have a bit more to go on. it will take me a little while to digest it all.

Comment: would I be correct in that even a blocking syscall "read()" would itself often be in a loop in a process, but, the process would "halt" (with the blocking syscall) until the kernel receives at least one character from keyboard, but then when control returns to process it just continues the loop one more iteration, making another blocking syscall "read()"? (and even if read() is not character-by-character, it still seems like a loop would be used in the process if waiting to read more things, like on a socket. )

Comment: @sawdust: It's still called "polling" much too often. One difference is that with poll() control _returns_ to where the process initially called it (i.e. the process has to actively _request_ the notification), while signals are delivered out-of-band and interrupt the regular flow (i.e. they're more or less unsolicited). So no, I wouldn't say it's the same definition at all.

Comment: if it receives input event structs or characters or not is good to know but not really what I asked. what I asked is, is the blocking syscall running all the time and returning all key presses, or does the process "refresh" the blocking syscall by issuing a new one each time the action of the previous one returns (thus using a loop maybe. )

Comment: A syscall cannot keep running while returning things, in general – once it has returned, it's no longer running and the control is back to the process.  The read() returns a certain amount of data, the process does something with that data, and then it has to call read() again. That's why I mentioned an "event loop" in the post.

Comment: ok thanks. and I assume that would be done using something like a loop in the process. or, if the blocking syscall triggers some kind of handler when it returns its thing. are "handlers" a thing or would it mostly be some kind of loop in the process?

Comment: "handlers" are not a thing, the call just returns to where it was initiated and it's up to the process to do something with its result. That's what distinguishes syscalls from signals...

Comment: ok thanks. so I assume process that wants to just read continuously would use a loop. so, "polling blocking syscalls" kind of :) you have both been very helpful. i will continue to digest both of your answers.

Comment: @user1686 "*It's still called "polling"*" __ Well, that's abusing the jargon, just like [interrupts vs dma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318145/dma-vs-interrupt-driven-i-o). Your conflating of **poll()** (the Linux syscall) and "*polls*" (the verb) is also problematic. The Linux **man** page for **poll()** clearly describes it as a "wait for some event". Waiting means suspension of the process until an event is handled.  Whereas to "*poll*" implies a repeated inquiry that does not relinquish control of the CPU.

Comment: I think you're both right. And you both tried to answer from my point of view. The blocking syscalls seem to be an intermediary between the two options I asked about. With "signals" I assumed the process had a handler (analogous to hardware interrupt to kernel. ) I also assumed process would register for "signals" once. But, with the blocking syscall, the kernel just returns control to the instruction after the call. And has to make another call, a form of "polling". An intermediary between the two assumptions I had.

Comment: @user1686 I might have a big picture overview now. "Event" is when process is waiting for I/O action from more than one thing. Assuming the word "event" also for a simple read() blocking system call (rather than poll() for multiple files), there is a loop, an "event loop", that refreshes the event request. The "event loop" with poll() is analogous but handling more cases (using a case statement or some if...else...). The "event handler" is this loop, rather than a "signal handler" (that analogous to "interrupt handler" is at predefined memory position. )